# How do I search a directory for 32-bit PNG files?

Tags: windows, search

I have a large directory of 8-bit PNG files which have been mixed with a few 32-bit PNG files.  I want to quickly find the PNG files which are 32-bits.
Viewing the properties will show this, but going through so many is going to be very time consuming.  How do I quickly find just the files that match the parameters I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution just occurred to me which is of course ridiculously simple. I can add bit-depth column and sort the files.
[image]